# VBScript variable - input two file types

Tags: xml, csv, vbscript, sftp

I've got a VBScript that pushes a .CSV file to a remote repository via SFTP. It's tested and works.

Now, I want it to also input a .XML file(if there is one in the given specified folder). How do I add this to the variable? I am unsure of the syntax.

Right now, I have

`File = "*.CSV"` and it reads any file in the directory that has .CSV extension. likewise, I can change this to .XML and it will work.

However, `File = "*.CSV, *.XML"` gives a syntax error, likewise `FILE = "*.CSV" & "*.XML"` provides nothing(no file is transferred).

How do I merge these two filetypes in one variable so it still reads both?

Comment: You also tried do something like this:

File = "*.avi|*.mpg|*.mkv|*.mp4"

Comment: I just tried `File = "*.XML|*.CSV"` and it did not work(no error in code, but the files are not pushed either)

Comment: Can you put how you call this 'File' to see more?

Comment: You do it twice. Once for each type. POst your code.

Comment: @bgalea ... I just facepalmed myself. Yes.. the aim is to automate this as a task in windows, so i'll just create a seperate task for .csv and one for .xml .. this is by far the fastest... modifying script for each. Oh well, sometimes the simplest things do it i guess.. thanks man

Comment: They can be in the same file. The aim is your code clearly shows what it is doing. When doing tasks sequentially is known as imperative programming. It's suited to sys admin stuff.